# django-select2 class-based or function based views

Tags: django, jquery-select2, django-select2

I'm thinking of using django-select2 project on my forms, but I'm mostly concerned about views do they have to be class-based views or I can use regular function views ?
In the documentation they only mention class-based views but didn't say a word about function based views (like in snippet below) so I don't know if it will work with my regular function views?
Thanks in advance.

https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

A simple class based view will do, to render your form:

```
# views.py
from django.views import generic

from . import forms, models


class BookCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Book
    form_class = forms.BookForm
    success_url = "/"
```

And I want to use it with the view like one below is:

```
def prilog_tacka_poziv_dodaj(request,poziv_id,tackapoziv_id):
    poziv=Poziv.objects.get(id=poziv_id)
    tackapoziv=TackaPoziv.objects.get(id=tackapoziv_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        forma=PrilogTackaPozivDodaj(request.POST)
        if forma.is_valid():
            forma.save()
            return redirect('poziv',poziv_id=poziv.id)
    else:
        forma=PrilogTackaPozivDodaj(initial={'tacka_poziv':tackapoziv})
    return render(request,'prilog_tacka_poziv_dodaj.html',{'forma':forma,'poziv':poziv,'tackapoziv':tackapoziv})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it and it works with function based views also!